# Can a Pi select the nearest Wi-Fi hotspot automatically?

Tags: pi-3, networking

I have set up two Wi-Fi hotspots with different SSIDs. Is it possible for a Raspberry Pi to calculate the signal strength of two Wi-Fi hotspots and connect to the hotspot with the highest signal strength?

Answer (score 3):

The wifi connection is done with `wpa-supplicant`. You have many options to set it up. Look at `man wpa_supplicant.conf`. It says:

> Configuration  file  can  include one or more network blocks, e.g.,
>   one for each used SSID. wpa_supplicant will automatically select the
>   best network based on the order of network blocks in the 
>   configuration  file,  network  security  level (WPA/WPA2 is
>   preferred), and signal strength.

Comment: is that posible ifi want to use python to get RSS value of all access point  and connect to selected access point if the access point with highest RSS value?

Comment: An answer to this you can find at [Python scan for WiFi](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21164401). Please use google e.g. with `python wifi scan` before asking.